# iOS: TableViewCell background for iPad on iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have some strange situation with background of TableViewCell when app is running  on iPads - on simulator or on a real device under iOS 9.

I use XCode 8.3 for developing my app. On iPhones application looks perfect. And I cannot found the cause. It happenes with all TableVies on iPad with iOS 9. With iOS 10.3 it works with no issues.

Here is my setup:

[image: setup]

How it looks like on iPad with iOS 10.3:

[image: iOS 10]

And how it looks like on iPad with iOS 9:

[image]

In the same time on iPhone 4S with iOS 9:

[image]

What makes the difference?

Comment: Could do the same color for the `contentView`?

Comment: Hey! Thank you! I've set the same colour for contentView of cell and it works fine now! Please post it as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As[Larme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1801544/larme) advised, I have changed background colour for content view of table view cell and it solved the issue.
[image]