# iOS Wrong disclosure background in UITableViewCell on iPad with iOS9

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, ios9, uiaccessoryview

I have similar issue like I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45654202/ios-tableviewcell-background-for-ipad-on-ios-9). And again I cannot find another hidden setting.

I used disclosure indicator for my table view cell. And working on iPhones/iPads with iOS 10+, iPhone with iOS 9 it looks fine, but not on iPad with iOS 9.

I have tried to set background for accessoryView, but it still the same.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TablesTableViewCell
    cell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
    if let tablesTable = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
        currentTableSession = TableSessionTable.getCurrentTableSession(table: tablesTable)
        cell.tableNameLabel.text = tablesTable.tableName
        print("cell.contant view")
        print(cell.contentView.backgroundColor)
        print("cell.accessory view")
        print(cell.accessoryView?.backgroundColor)
        print("tableview.background")
        print(tableView.backgroundColor)
```

As per print, it's nil:

> cell.contant view Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.976539 0.977373
>   0.915492 1)  cell.accessory view nil
>   tableview.background Optional(UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.976539 0.977373 0.915492 1)

Also tried this:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryView?.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor
```

Same result.

Any idea how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution!
Thanks for Claude31 who helped me with with this issue on Apple Developers forum.

Finally I have found that the issue can be fixed by initializing backgroundView and setting colour:

```
let backgroundView = UIView()  
backgroundView.backgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor  
cell.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

It works!